# Android Activity or iOS ViewController inside of Xamarin Forms ContentPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms ContentPage with StackLayout. I also have a Native Android Activity, and a Native iOS ViewController. I want to display the Android Activity or iOS ViewController inside of my StackLayout (below my other content) depending on the OS. Is this possible, if yes how can i do it?

Comment: You could take a look at direction of [embedding native controls inside `Xamarin.Forms` page](https://blog.xamarin.com/adding-bindable-native-views-directly-to-xaml/). You could create custom controls on each platfrom and then try to add it inside your `Xamarin.Forms` page. I'm not sure that it's possible for whole `Activity`/`ViewController`.

Comment: Yes but can i access the custom controls from native Android Activity / native iOS ViewController ?

Comment: Separately from Activity, I suppose, yes.

Comment: In Android, actually  the ContentPage is placed in an Android Activity container, so the question becomes whether an Activity can display another Activity in side of it, it is clear that this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

At this time Xamarin.Forms only allows you to insert Native Views  `(UIView, and Android.Widget.View)`, take a look at those examples of add native controls to Xamarin Forms:

[iOS](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.ControlGallery.iOS/AppDelegate.cs#L185)
[Android](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.ControlGallery.Android/Activity1.cs#L338)